# How to solve TLS error in Filezilla FTP client?

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, sftp, tls

When i try to connect a site files by Filezilla FTP client, i get the following error

```
Status:        Connecting to 91.109.7.88:21...
Status:        Connection established, initializing TLS...
Error:        GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Error:        Could not connect to server
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Which protocol do you use on server and client side? Could you check the server's protocol/service with nmap?

Comment: maybe a firewall problem, try to use a proxy.

Comment: did you solve the problem?  maybe this one does: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637810/vsftpd-gnutls-error-15-an-unexpected-tls-packet-was-received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Status:        Connecting to 91.109.7.88:21...
Status:        Connection established, initializing TLS...
Error:        GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

There is probably a problem with your settings, i.e. how you connect to the server.

It looks you are trying to do implicit TLS,  where TLS gets used directly after the TCP connection got established. But this is wrong when using the standard FTP port 21, because in this case explicit TLS is expected, where it first creates a plain TCP connection and then upgrades this connection to TLS after issuing a `AUTH TLS` command.

Comment: So you told that i have to use plain FTP.right?

Comment: Filezilla uses the FTPES:// schema for this case, see  https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/SSL/TLS#Explicit_vs_Implicit_FTPS